Reactjs logs user out every 10s of inactivity not working
I want to log user out every 10 min of inactivity in react js but it log user out whether they are active or not every 10 mins
const Layout = () => {
    var timer;

    const events = [
        "load",
        "mousemove",
        "mousedown",
        "click",
        "scroll",
        "keypress",
    ];
    // this function sets the timer that logs out the user after 10 secs
    const handleLogoutTimer = () => {

        timer = setTimeout(() => {
            // clears any pending timer.
            resetTimer();
            // Listener clean up. Removes the existing event listener from the window
            Object.values(events).forEach((item) => {
                window.removeEventListener(item, resetTimer);
            });
            // logs out user
            logoutAction();
        }, 1000000); // 10000ms = 10secs. You can change the time.
    };

    // this resets the timer if it exists.
    const resetTimer = () => {
        if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        Object.values(events).forEach((item) => {
            window.addEventListener(item, () => {
                resetTimer();
                handleLogoutTimer();
            });
        });
    }, []);

    // logs out user by clearing out auth token in localStorage and redirecting url to /signin page.
    const logoutAction = () => {
        localStorage.clear();
        console.log("Sign out")
    };


    return (
        <div>
            <Row>
                <Col lg={5} className=''>
                    <Aside />
                </Col>
                <Col xl={19} lg={19} md={19} sm={24} xs={24}>
                    <Row>
                        <Col span={24}>
                            <Navbar />
                        </Col>
                        <Col span={24}>
                            <div className="outlet">
                                <Outlet />
                            </div>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Layout


Probably what is wrong is you are using one global timer for each of the different events. But since it is 6 different event listeners and 6 different setTimeout you also need 6 different timer variables.
As it is, timer is just the value of the last defined event listener, so you never clear the timeout of the first 5.
I would highly recommend to use useState as well for the timers. Something like
const [timers, setTimers] = useState({
  load: null,
  mousemove: null,
  mousedown: null,
  click: null,
  scroll: null,
  keypress: null,
});

...

// Example: set timer for scroll event
const timer = setTimeout(..);
setTimers({...timers, scroll: timer});

Then you will need to make sure any of these events clears the timers for all the others.
